# Close a BufferedReader in a Iterator for returning file lines

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I wrote the following class for an iterator that iterates along the lines of a file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class FileIterator implements Iterator<String> {

private BufferedReader reader;

public FileIterator(String filename) {
  this.reader = getBufferedReader(filename);
}


private static BufferedReader getBufferedReader(String filename) {

  File file = new File(filename); 
  if(file.exists()) {
    try {
          return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(new File(filename)),"UTF-8"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
          return null;
    }
  } else {
        System.out.println(filename + " is not there");
        return null;
  }
}

public boolean hasNext() {
  try {
    return reader.ready();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
  }
}

public String next() {
  try {
    return reader.readLine();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}

public void remove() {}
}
```

Now my question is a bit naive. Will be the reader closed once the iterator is no more used, when the GC will take care of it? Would the class improve if I close the reader manually?  Maybe as a side effect in the hasNext() method:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
  try {
        if(reader.ready()) return true;
        else {
          reader.close();
      return false;
        }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Problems like these are a major part of the reason that you probably _shouldn't_ use an `Iterator` like this.

Comment: I know, but I needed a fast implementation of an Iterator<String> for an interface I had to test... Then I was wondering if I can do something else out of it.

Comment: You shouldn't do anything else with an iterator that can be created for a non-existing file, and then throw a NullPointerException when hasNext() is called. That's an awkward behavior.

Comment: By the way: throw `UnsupportedOperationException` from `remove()`

Comment: @davide: If you're just using a handful of `String`s for a test, why not just use `Arrays.asList("example1", "example2", "example3").iterator()`?

Comment: I have my good reasons for what I've done. I'm not totally unschooled.

Comment: By the way thanks to all of you, I really learned something tonight!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this, I would have FileIterator implement Closeable and delegate the call to the underlying BufferedReader.  You could even use it in a Java 7 [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block.

Comment: why would he not want to do this? what else would he want to do instead? (smells like there's a best-practice somewhere)

Comment: Well it's a bit of an abuse of the Iterable interface because you can only iterate over it once.  But so is Java's DirectoryStream so maybe it's not that bad.  I have a LineIterable class that we use a lot at work so I can't say it's a horrible idea :)